# convert dataframe to fasttext data format

Tags: python, pandas, fasttext

I want to convert a dataframe to fasttext format

my dataframe

```
text                                                             label 
Fan bake vs bake                                                 baking
What's the purpose of a bread box?                               storage-method
Michelin Three Star Restaurant; but if the chef is not there     restaurant
```

fast text format

```
__label__baking Fan bake vs bake
__label__storage-method What's the purpose of a bread box?
__label__restaurant Michelin Three Star Restaurant; but if the chef is not there
```

I tried `df['label'].apply(lambda x: '__label__' + x).add_suffix(df['text'])`
But it doesn't work as I expected. How should I change my code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
'__label__'+df['label']+' '+df['text']
```